# Deserializing JSON in API fuction works from VS/Browser, not when called from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, vb.net, visual-studio

I have the following class in a VB project, it's an ASMX service (bit old fashioned, I know):

```
Public Class cName
    Public Property nameOrAlias As String
    Public Property nameType As String
    Public Property isVerified As String
    Public Property nameID As String
    Public Property icn As String
End Class
```

And I use it in the following function:

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Function SaveCaseNames(jsn As String) As String

        Try
            Dim json As String = jsn

            Dim d As New DataTable
            Dim c As New cShared

            Dim s As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
            Dim sql As String = ""
            Dim icn As String = ""
            Dim sArgs As String = ""

            Dim o As Object = s.Deserialize(Of Object)(json)


            Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
            Dim lstNames = js.Deserialize(Of List(Of cName))(json)

            'First we look for new names, those without a nameID
            For Each cx As cName In lstNames

                icn = cx.icn.ToString
                If cx.nameID.ToString = "--" Then

                    sArgs &= "'" & icn & "', "
                    sArgs &= "'" & cx.nameOrAlias.ToString & "', "
                    sArgs &= "'" & cx.nameType.ToString & "', "

                    Select Case cx.isVerified.ToString
                        Case "YES"
                            sArgs &= "1"
                        Case "NO"
                            sArgs &= "0"
                    End Select

                    sql = "sp_insertCaseNames " & sArgs
                    d = c.GetDataTable(c.SetConnection(), sql)
                    d.TableName = "insertNames"

                End If



            Next

            'if it has a D the entry should be deleted.
            For Each cx As cName In lstNames
                If cx.nameID.ToString.StartsWith("D") Then
                    Dim nameID As String = Replace(cx.nameID.ToString, "D", "")
                    sql = "UPDATE casenames Set st_id = 4 WHERE id = " & nameID
                    d = c.GetDataTable(c.SetConnection(), sql)
                    d.TableName = "deleteNames"
                End If
            Next

            Return "HELLO WORLD!"

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Using tables is a bit funny of course since neither of the two data calls returns anything but I am not done with writing the helper functions yet and at any rate isn't what this question is about.

If I run the project in VS 2015 it runs fine. I pass the following JSON to the function above and all works.

```
[{"nameOrAlias":"TEST 4","nameType":"MIDDLE","isVerified":"YES","nameID":"16","icn":"N2016000020"},{"nameOrAlias":"TEST1","nameType":"AKA","isVerified":"YES","nameID":"D15","icn":"N2016000020"},{"nameOrAlias":"TESTXXX101","nameType":"AKA","isVerified":"YES","nameID":"17","icn":"N2016000020"},{"nameOrAlias":"HELLO JOE","nameType":"AKA","isVerified":"YES","nameID":"--","icn":"N2016000020"}]
```

The record with "TEST1" is deleted and "HELLO JOE" is added.

When I call that exact same function with the exact same JSON array from my web page using jQuery, like so:

```
//Save the case names (aliases)
var jsonString = sessionStorage.getItem('caseNames');


var str = JSON.stringify(jsonString);
if (debug == 'true') {
    alert(str);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myserver.net/dps/svc/DeadSimple.asmx/SaveCaseNames",
    data: str,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert('YAY!!!!!!!!!');
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert('Fail! ' + response.d);
    }
});
```

I get an error message:

> {"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to
>   type
>   \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

I have tried this with and without `JSON.stringify`, no success. I also wrapped the array as in: `var str = JSON.stringify('{data:' + jsonString + '}');` but that just made it harder to parse because now the objects I am after were a level deeper and it didn't solve the issue anyway.

What is causing this? If I F5 the web service in VS and call it directly from the browser, it works. HELP! the Target framework for the class lib is 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wish I had seen this [receive JSON array as argument in web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182848/receive-json-array-as-argument-in-web-service) before...

It's basically as simple as changing the function declaration to:

```
Public Function SaveCaseNames(jsn() As cName) As String
```

Then you can easily loop through the entire JSON array with very simple code like so:

```
For Each c As cName In jsn
    Debug.Print (c.propertyNameOfYourChoice)
Next
```

You just have to make sure to format the JSON string you are passing as the array is formatted correctly. It's a bit perculiar... It also doesn't answer why my previous attempt works directly from the browser and not from an `$.ajax` call...